# Getting the result of cursor and turning it into a string for TextView

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

This is my query :

```
Cursor nextdate(String Date) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] params = new String[]{String.valueOf(Date)};
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(" SELECT MIN (" + colDateDue + ") FROM " + PAYMENTS + " WHERE " + colDateDue + ">=?", params);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    return cur;
}
```

I want to display the result of that query in a TextView but I don't know how to, so naturally I look for an answer. I find a few answers around and come up with this :

```
DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
String str = "";
    if (c!= null) {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            str = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(db.colDateDue);
        }
    }
TextView.setText(str);
```

But I get the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

Which got me a bit confused since the usual fix for that error is using `cur.moveToFirst();` which is used in both instances... what am I doing wrong exactly?

Comment: do `str = c.getString(0);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this:

keep the column index as 0 because that cursor will have only one column.

```
DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
String str = "";
    if (c!= null) {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            str = c.getString(0);
        }
    }
TextView.setText(str);
```

Comment: I seem to be getting a NullPointerException now pointing at my `setText(str)` still trying to work it out.

Comment: where you initialized that textview.

Comment: Declared before my `onCreate` and defined within the `onCreate` where I'm also doing the cursor interpretation.

Comment: am not asking about declaration asking about initialization?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work. I made a small error and put them BEFORE my `setContentView`. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to use the index of `db.colDateDue`. However, that does not correlate with your actual query. You can happily pull the first result with:

```
str = c.getString(0);
```